# DataRows to DataTable

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

I want to merge two `DataTable` into a single `DataTable`, problem is that it doesn't have a primary key. I some how achieved it by using this code.

```
var result = (from t1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
                          join t2 in table2.AsEnumerable()
                          on table1.Rows.IndexOf(t1) equals table2.Rows.IndexOf(t2)
                          select  new { t1, t2 });
```

But my result is an anonymous type of `DataRow`. I want to convert it to a new `DataTable`

Answer (score 0):

Your linq doesn't return a `DataRow` at all; it returns an *anonymous tuple of two* `DataRows`. (Or rather an `Enumarable` of it)

I don't think you can create a new `DataRow` from that with a simple (or not so simple ) linq.

Instead you will need to create the rows from the new `DataTable` (**after** creating that table) and then fill the fields one by one.

The reason is that [DataRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't have a meaningful constructor.

To create a `DataRow` you always need a `DataTable`; then a function can be written:

```
DataRow MergeRows(DataTable dt, DataRow row1, DataRow row2)
{
    var row3 = dt.NewRow();

    for (int i = 0; i < row1.ItemArray.Length; i++)
    {
        row3.SetField(i, row1.ItemArray[i]);
    }
    int colCount1 = row1.ItemArray.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < row2.ItemArray.Length; i++)
    {
        row3.SetField(i + colCount1 , row2.ItemArray[i]);
    }
    return row3;
}
```

This assumes that the fields will match.

To create the 3rd `DataTable` simply add all the columns; there are ways to use `DataTable.Merge()` but it is probably simpler to use a little helper function:

```
List<DataColumn> MergeColumns(DataTable dt1, DataTable dt2)
{
  var cols = new List<DataColumn>();
  foreach (DataColumn c in dt1.Columns) cols.Add(new DataColumn(c.ColumnName, c.DataType));
  foreach (DataColumn c in dt2.Columns) cols.Add(new DataColumn(c.ColumnName, c.DataType));
  return cols;
}
```

And add the result:

```
table3.Columns.AddRange(MergeColumns(table1, table2).ToArray());
```

Now your linq can be changed to

```
 var result = (from t1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
                      join t2 in table2.AsEnumerable()
                      on table1.Rows.IndexOf(t1) equals table2.Rows.IndexOf(t2)
                      select MergeRows(table3, t1, t2) );
```

Now you can create the 3rd `DataTable` (again!) from the rows:

```
if (result.Count() > 0)
    table3 =  result.Cast<DataRow>().ToArray().CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Done; please try if this works for you. I does here.

Comment: Sure just two loops should do..See my update! Note that the code assumes you want to add all columns.

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, please consider consider [accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it..! - I see that you have never done this: Go the the (invisible) checkmark at the top left, below the votes of the answer and click it! It turns green and gains us both a little reputation..